# Uneditable actionPerformed block in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, methods

I'm currently developing an inventory system and accidentally cleared out the

```
// TODO add your handling code here:
```

portion.

now i need to insert some code but the braces won't budge and the method looks like this.

```
private void flucRxTxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
}
```

What should I do to insert my code?

Comment: Did you try CTL+Z (Undo)?

Comment: wont work, method was edited days ago :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your cursor at the beginning of the line with the closing curly brace, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Now you can insert as many new lines as you want.

Comment: oh that was nice, i can do so much complicated stuff yet cannot handle these types of errors. :)
thanks!